# How to use python to find an angle in a SSS triangle via the cosine rule?

Tags: python, trigonometry

I am creating a massive calculator in python, but I have come a across an issue. I am trying to use the law of cosines to find the angle in an SSS triangle and I cannot see where i am going wrong.

```
    elif qchoice5 == 4:
    while True:
        try:
            print("======================================================================")
            a = float(input("what is side a?"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("======================================================================")
            print("please enter a valid option")
    while True:
        try:
            print("======================================================================")
            b = float(input("what is side b?"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("======================================================================")
            print("Please enter a valid option")
    while True:
        try:
            print("======================================================================")
            c = float(input("what is side c?"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("======================================================================")
            print("Please enter a valid option")
    print(((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2*a*b))
    ans = math.acos((((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2*a*b)))
    print(ans)
```

Whenever run it it gives the error

```
    ans = math.degrees(math.acos((((b*b)+(c*c)-(a*a))/(2*a*b))))
    ValueError: math domain error
```

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to get this working?

Comment: You talk about SSS in the context of congruent triangles. In this instance, you should be checking to make sure that x + y > z for all sides in this triangle.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In particular, give us a set of assigned a, b, c values that provoke the problem.

Comment: `math.acos((((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2*a*b)))` - look at this expression. Now look at the law of cosines. Now back to your expression. Do you see a discrepancy? Redo your algebra.

Comment: @Prune I've found that in order for it not to return an error A must = the largest, B = the smallest and c must = the middle number. Even then though it gives the wrong answee.

Comment: Not really: your code solves for only one of the angles.  Regardless of which one you choose, the law of cosines will work.  As I mentioned in my answer, and @user2357112 caught at about the same time, your formula is incorrect.  If you correct the formula, you should be able to get the appropriate angle.  Permuting the side values will get you each of the three angles.

Answer (score 0):

Without a valid MCVE, I can only do this from a QA standpoint.  I see some problems:

1. You never validate your input.  A non-triangle, such as sides of 2, 3, 100, will leave you taking `acos` of a value out of range.
2. Your computation is incorrect: b^2 + c^2 - a^2 would need to be divided by `2bc`, not `2ab`.

FYI, if you're working with integers in Python 2, you'll run into a problem: the division is integer division, and pretty much everything will return `acos(0)`, which is math.pi/2

Try this to correct the last two problems (#2 and the integer division):

```
ans = math.acos((((b**2)+(c**2)-(a**2))/(2.0*b*c)))
```